Why in literature photon temperature is considered to scale as $T\propto a^{-1}$ before decoupling in the matter dominated era?
We know in cosmology $s a^3=const$ where s contains entropy of all particles in thermal equilibrium.
However, in matter dominated era, since $s={p+\rho\over T}$,so matter also dominates the entropy.
in particular, we have $n_{matter}=g_i ({m_iT\over 2\pi})^{3\over 2}e^{\mu -m\over T}$ and $\rho_{matter}=m_i n$
So, before decoupling in the matter dominated era, it is clear that photon temperature doesn't scale as $T\propto a^{-1}$. In other words, the matter take back part of the entropy in the matter dominated era before photon decouples, resulting in an additional drop in photon temperature during that period.
However, since it is unlikely that physicists have made such a mistake for decades, it must be that there is a flaw in my reasoning.
